# Nuxt dynamic nested routes with only one layer using nuxt-child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Given I have the current structure:

```
pages/
--| _user/
-----| _list/
--------| _bookmark/
-----------| index.vue
--------| index.vue
-----| _list.vue
```

I am then trying to achieve a structure where you can visit a users profile.

```
/<profile-name>
```

then visit a list they made with a children route displaying the child

```
/<profile-name>/<list-name>
```

And this works well; I have the `_list.vue` used as a parent, and the `_list/index.vue` showing inside.

But now I want to add a route for

```
/<profile-name>/<list-name>/<bookmark-name>
```

Which should NOT use the parent for `_list.vue`

**However, the `_bookmark/index.vue` is embedded inside the `_list.vue` I want it to be an entirely independent page of its own.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, I had to move the page from the `/pages` folder and into the `components` folder.

This way, I could prevent Nuxt from automatically generating an undesired route, and I could then extend the routes through the router config like this manually:

```
router: {
  extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
    routes.push({
      name: 'bookmark',
      path: '/:slug/:list/:id',
      component: resolve(__dirname, 'components/pages/bookmark.vue')
    })
  }
}
```